# Compiler throwing error as variable is not declared X++

Tags: axapta, x++, morph-x

I have the following piece of `x++` code:

```
static void Datatypes_class_variable(Args _args)
{
    // Declare a class variable from the RentalInfo class
    RentalInfo   rentalInfo;
    ;
    // An object is created and referenced by the
    // class variable rentalInfo
    rentalInfo = new RentalInfo();
    // Call methods to set/get data to/from the object
    rentalInfo.setCar("BMW 320");
    info(strfmt("The car is a %1", rentalInfo.getCar()));
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler is throwing me the error:

> The RentalInfo variable was not declared.

As you can see, the variable has been already declared at the beginning.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `RentalInfo` does not exist as a class.

That is why the error is in line 4 column 4.

Comment: You're right Jan. I can't believe I've missed this one. Thank you!